# Nginx proxy cache invalidating request to s3

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, proxy, cache, amazon-s3

I have set up a proxy from my application server to a private s3 bucket to cache requests. I was having some trouble with it where s3 was rejecting my download requests (403 forbidden) and after some experimentation it seems that disabling cacheing allows the valid request to go through. But the entire purpose of the proxy is as a cache. I guess the proxy is altering the request in some way but I don't understand how. Does anyone have any insight into how enabling caching in nginx alters requests and if there is some way to over come this?

Here is the relevent config.

```
http {

    proxy_cache_path          /home/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=S3_CACHE:10m inactive=24h max_size=500m;
    proxy_temp_path           /home/cache/tmp;

    server {

        server_name my-cache-server.com;
        listen 80;

        proxy_cache S3_CACHE;

        location / {

            proxy_buffering        on;
            proxy_pass             http://MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/;
            proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        }
    }
}
```

if I remove the line `proxy_cache S3_CACHE;`

Comment: How are you passing authentication to the S3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is good enough for cache responses from S3, it also supports cache invalidation on demand, for example:

```
curl -I 'https://domain/s3/file.jpg' -H 'Cache-Purge: 1'
```

In case of caching proxy Nginx doesn't do subsequent HTTP request to S3 if the response is on disk already (file name based on proxy directory + md5 of response).

See the full config there: https://gist.github.com/mikhailov/9639593